# php filemtime 24 hr format

Tags: php, date, format

I created this code to get the date a file was last touched then display it to the user in AM/PM format.

It doesn't seem to be working though. I know I'm close; what am I doing wrong?

```
$filename = 'test.html';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $date = date(filemtime($filename));
    clearstatcache();
}
echo "- last updated: " . date('F d Y h:i A', strtotime($date));
```

Output: last updated: December 31 1969 06:59 PM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $date = filemtime($filename);
    clearstatcache();
}
echo "- last updated: " . date('F d Y h:i A', $date);
```

In your code, this line:

```
$date = date(filemtime($filename));
```

wouldn't work since `filemtime` returns a UNIX timestamp, which you are then passing as the first parameter to `date()`. Even if that did work, you are then converting that date back to a UNIX timestamp with `strtotime()`, and then back into a date string again which seems a little inefficient.

Also consider what happens if the file doesn't exist, will `$date` have been set elsewhere in your code?

Comment: The file will always exist so im not concerned. Im trying your fix now. One moment pls.

Comment: In that case perhaps move the echo inside of your if statement?

Comment: The code works like a charm. Thanks for the simple fix :) Ill accept asap (blocked for the next 4 min)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date(filemtime($filename));
```

That line is wrong. First argument to `date()` is a format string. Replace with:

```
$date = filemtime($filename);
```

Also, you don't need to perform `strtotime()` on a timestamp, just use as is:

```
echo date('F d Y h:i A', $date);
```